# Unable to deploy on heroku: .env and PORT error

Tags: reactjs, express, heroku, environment-variables

The app works on localhost:3000. I set app.listen(3000).
However, when I deploy the app to heroku, it stops working. I updated the code to: port = process.env.PORT || 80 and port = process.env.PORT || 443 and added a .env file with the client secret and client id. Set the PORT in .env as 443 and it still fails to work.

Server.js:

```js
app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    const code = req.body.code
    const spotifyApi = new WebApi({
        redirectUri: process.env.REDIRECT_URI,
        clientId:  process.env.CLIENT_ID,
        clientSecret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET
    })

    spotifyApi
    .authorizationCodeGrant(code)
    .then(data => {
        res.json({
            accessToken: data.body.access_token,
            refreshToken: data.body.refresh_token,
            expiresIn: data.body.expires_in,
        })
    })
    .catch(err => {
        res.sendStatus(400)
    })
})

app.get("/lyrics", async (req, res) => {
    const lyrics = 
    (await lyricsFinder(req.query.artist, req.query.track)) || "Lyrics Unavailable for this Song"
    res.json({lyrics})
})

port = process.env.PORT || 80
```

Authorization.js:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    axios.post('http://localhost:3001/login', {
        code,
}).then(res => {
    setAccessToken(res.data.accessToken)
    setRefreshToken(res.data.refreshToken)
    setExpiresIn(res.data.expiresIn)
    window.history.pushState({}, null, "/")
}).catch(() => {
    window.location = "/"
})
}, [code])
```

The app either goes back to login page or gives a POST/GET error.

I tried deployed the app on heroku with the following code and it works as long as I deploy it on my local host. I am aware that .listen doesn't work after deploying to heroku as the PORT is dynamically assigned.

```js
app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    const code = req.body.code
    const spotifyApi = new WebApi({
        redirectUri: process.env.REDIRECT_URI,
        clientId:  process.env.CLIENT_ID,
        clientSecret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET
    })

    spotifyApi
    .authorizationCodeGrant(code)
    .then(data => {
        res.json({
            accessToken: data.body.access_token,
            refreshToken: data.body.refresh_token,
            expiresIn: data.body.expires_in,
        })
    })
    .catch(err => {
        res.sendStatus(400)
    })
})

app.get("/lyrics", async (req, res) => {
    const lyrics = 
    (await lyricsFinder(req.query.artist, req.query.track)) || "Lyrics Unavailable for this Song"
    res.json({lyrics})
})

app.listen(3001)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the PORT variable when defining where the server listens to

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`))
```

Comment: I updated the code from local host to the website link and added the suggestion to the code.
Here is what I got:
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 404 Not Found

Comment: It is now deploying (you can check the logs to confirm), it looks now the URL you are invoking is incorrect or something wrong in the endpoint. What do you invoke?

Comment: Been testing all the solutions I could find on stackoverflow and failing. I usually add the Heroku url (ex: spotify.heroku.com) to the auth url and the login url (ex: spotify.heroku.com/login) and add the same in the Redirect URIs of the API.

Comment: did you figure this out?